# Using CSS to resize a <div> to a dimension smaller than its current width and height

Tags: css, gwt, resize

I currently have a div whose css looks like this:

```
.class
{
overflow:auto;
resize: both;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
```

I want the user to be able to resize the div so that the resulting width and height can be less than 100px. How is this possible?

EDIT: Some context. I want this feature because I am developing an application where a user can resize a widget and saves this width and height to a server so that the size is saved across sessions. As it is currently setup, when the user stops resizing, my code resets the div's width and height properties dynamically. It works great if the user is making the div larger. However the user cannot then make the div any smaller.

EDIT2: I am using GWT to develop this application. More specifically, this div is just an AbsolutePanel.

Comment: How does the user do this? voice commands? telepathy? fill in a form? draggables?

Comment: @Diodeus: it seems to me that the OP is relying on the resize property of the CSS3 Basic User Interface Module http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#resize, to allow the user to resize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little vague, can't you just make the panel a [LayoutPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/LayoutPanel.html)?

Get/set the height and width with [the *Style* methods](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Style.html) of the [DOM client package](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/package-summary.html).  Specifically, [getHeight()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Style.html#getHeight%28%29), [setHeight()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Style.html#setHeight%28double,%20com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.Unit%29), [getWidth()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Style.html#getWidth%28%29), and [setWidth()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Style.html#setWidth%28double,%20com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.Unit%29).

Comment: These functions are indeed what I already use, just with an AbsolutePanel. The reason I need to use the browser's CSS resize capacity is to allow the user an interface to set these dimensions.How else would I easily pass user-defined values into these parameters?

Comment: Use a LayoutPanel, not an AbsolutePanel. If the user is resizing by dragging, monitor the resize events using the handy features LayoutPanels provide.  If the user is typing-in numbers, feed those to the setter functions.  They all operate with the browser's CSS / JS.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to look at a javascript solution (jquery-ui has some nice libraries like http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/) to allow the user to resize screen elements.

Otherwise, change your values to percentages (instead of pixels) and let the user resize their window to resize the element (joking, although that would work, technically)

Comment: I really want a solution that doesn't rely on a js library like jquery , since I am already using GWT.