# Css resize min-width

Tags: css, webkit, resize

I want to make a div resizable with `resize` css property:

```css
#foo {
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}
```

I can freely resize it with firefox.

with chrome/safari I can't resize it smaller than initial size.

their is a way to allow resize smaller with webkit? (`min-width` / `min-height` don't works)

see the live exemple from MDN (with 2 nested divs)
https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/resize.html

Answer (score 4):

Better solution is to use :active pseudo class e.g:

```
div:active {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kronenbear/v4Lq5o09/1/

Comment: Nice trick! The "disappearing flash" is not pleasant, but it does the job: resizable elements without a single line of JavaScript. Can anyone do better and avoid this flash?

Answer (score 2):

Using that live example as a reference, I was able to set the initial size to be equal to the width and height of the div, and the min-height and min-width to be the minimum dimensions allowable in Chrome.

```css
    #foo {
      resize: both;
      overflow: scroll;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      min-width: 50px;
      min-height: 70px;
    }
    div {
      background-color: #acacac;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a small workaround that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985133/resize-a-div-to-smaller-than-its-declared-size), but it does work.

On hover, change the height and width to `1px`

```
#foo:hover{
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
}
```

It sounds like this will cause a slight "flash" as the width and height are dramatically changing, but ... it is a hack.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying for hours but can't make it to work better than the hack, if I could just trigger a userresize I would be happy setting chrome's width to min-width then trigger resize to put it where I want, since it seems that you can move it back to original position after moving. But I don't find how to.